# Join users to a new conversation and start exchanging messages with signalR

Tags: c#, angular, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

I have the following signalR service on Angular to communicate with my signalR server:

```
export class SignalService {
    private hubConnection: signalR.HubConnection;
    private messageSubject = new Subject<ConversationSignalMessage>();
    public messageReceived$ = this.messageSubject.asObservable();
    
    constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
        this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl(`https://localhost:5001/sampleHub?userId=${user.id}`, { withCredentials: false})
        .build();

        this.hubConnection.on('MessageReceived', (chatId: string, message: Message) => {
            if (message.userSender.id == user.id)
                return;

            this.messageSubject.next(new ConversationSignalMessage(chatId, message));
        });
    }

    startConnection(): Promise<any> {
        return this.hubConnection.start();
    }

    joinChat(chatId: string, participant: Participant): void {
        this.hubConnection.invoke('Join', chatId, participant)
        .catch(err => console.error(`Error joining chat: ${err}`));
    }

    sendMessage(chatId: string, message: Message): void {
        this.hubConnection.invoke('SendMessage', chatId, message)
        .catch(err => console.error(`Error sending message: ${err}`));
    }

    createConversation(users: string[], chatId: string, message: Message): void {
        this.hubConnection.invoke('CreateConversation', users, chatId, message)
        .catch(err => console.error(`Error creating conversation and joining users: ${err}`));
    }

    getMessageStream(): Observable<ConversationSignalMessage> {
        return this.messageSubject.asObservable();
    }

    stopConnection(): Promise<any> {
        return this.hubConnection.stop();
    }
}
```

And this is my signalR c# hub:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> _connectedUsers = new();
private readonly Dictionary<Guid, List<string>> _conversationParticipants = new();
private readonly Dictionary<Guid, List<Message>> _conversationMessages = new();

public async Task SendMessage(Guid chatId, Message message)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{conversationId}: {message.Text}");
    await Clients.Groups(chatId.ToString()).SendAsync("MessageReceived", chatId, message).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

public async Task Join(Guid chatId, Participant participant)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{participant.UserName} joined {chatId}.");
    await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, chatId.ToString()).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

public async Task LeaveConversation(Guid chatId) => await Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, chatId.ToString()).ConfigureAwait(false);

public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
{
    string userId = Context.GetHttpContext().Request.Query["userId"];
    _connectedUsers[Context.ConnectionId] = userId;
    await base.OnConnectedAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    Console.WriteLine($"Client `{userId}` connected.");
}

public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
{
    if (_connectedUsers.TryGetValue(Context.ConnectionId, out string userId))
    {
        _ = _connectedUsers.Remove(Context.ConnectionId);
        Console.WriteLine($"Client `{userId}` disconnected.");
    }

    await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

public async Task CreateConversation(List<string> users, Guid chatId, Message message)
{
    string creatorConnectionId = Context.ConnectionId;

    _conversationParticipants[conversationId] = userIds;

    if (!_conversationMessages.ContainsKey(conversationId))
    {
        _conversationMessages[conversationId] = new List<Message>();
    }

    _conversationMessages[conversationId].Add(message);

    foreach (var userId in users)
    {
        if (_connectedUsers.ContainsValue(userId.ToString()))
        {
            await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(creatorConnectionId, chatId.ToString()).ConfigureAwait(false);
            Console.WriteLine($"{userId} joined {chatId}.");
        }
    }

    // Frontend not listening this call.
    await Clients.Groups(chatId.ToString()).SendAsync("ConversationCreated", chatId).ConfigureAwait(false);

   await Clients.Groups(chatId.ToString()).SendAsync("MessageReceived", chatId, message).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

At the moment I can start a new conversation between me and another user. I can send a message, but the other user doesn't receive it until he refreshes the full page (basically it's loading the chat from the database). After this refresh the **Join** method is invoked and now I can send a message and he will receive it (via SendMessage), this is working fine.

What I'm trying to do is once that I create a new conversation between me, and another user automatically create a new conversation channel (hub... maybe?) and create the connection (similar to what "Join" does) and finally, once that both users are connected a listening to the new conversation channel, I want to start sharing messages between them (similar to what "SendMessage" does).

At the moment I created the code from CreateConversation and I can see the Console.WriteLine($"{userId} joined {chatId}."); message on my console but after I send a message the other user never receives the message. What I'm doing wrong or what can I do to accomplish what I'm trying here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Try to implement the feature like below.

```
public async Task CreateConversation(List<string> users, Guid chatId, Message message)
{
    // creator
    string creatorConnectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
    // get all the userIds from this chat channel by conversationId
    _conversationParticipants[conversationId] = userIds;
    // route all the message to the correct chat channel 
    if (!_conversationMessages.ContainsKey(conversationId))
    {
        _conversationMessages[conversationId] = new List<Message>();
    }
    // add the message to the correct chat channel 
    _conversationMessages[conversationId].Add(message);

    // foreach the users and get all the connectedUsers by userid(s)
    // like below
    foreach (var userId in users)
    {
        List<string>() tempConnectionsListForSingleUser = new List<string>();

        // get all the connections by userid, one user could have a lot of connectionid
        tempConnectionsListForSingleUser = _connectedUsers.TryGetValue(userid, out existUserConnectionIds);
        
        // foreach tempConnectionsListForSingleUser 
        // add all the connections into the chat channel

        foreach (string item in tempConnectionsListForSingleUser)
        {
           await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(item, chatId.ToString()).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        
        //if (_connectedUsers.ContainsValue(userId.ToString()))
        //{
            //await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(creatorConnectionId, chatId.ToString()).ConfigureAwait(false);
            //Console.WriteLine($"{userId} joined {chatId}.");
        //}
     }

     await Clients.Groups(chatId.ToString()).SendAsync("ConversationCreated", chatId).ConfigureAwait(false);

     await Clients.Groups(chatId.ToString()).SendAsync("MessageReceived", chatId, message).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

---

The root casue is not listening the `ConversationCreated` event in front-end.

To put it simply,

```
await Clients.Groups(chatId.ToString()).SendAsync("ConversationCreated", chatId).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This method on the backend will call `hubConnection.on('ConversationCreated')` in frontend. The front and back ends need to be matched one by one.

---

Change below code

```
foreach (var userId in users)
{
    if (_connectedUsers.ContainsValue(userId.ToString()))
    {
        await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(creatorConnectionId, chatId.ToString()).ConfigureAwait(false);
        Console.WriteLine($"{userId} joined {chatId}.");
    }
}
```

To

```
private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>> ConnectedUsers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>>();
...
//use below code in your OnConnectedAsync and other method
List<string>? existUserConnectionIds;
ConnectedUsers.TryGetValue(userid, out existUserConnectionIds);
if (existUserConnectionIds == null)
{
existUserConnectionIds = new List<string>();
}
existUserConnectionIds.Add(Context!.ConnectionId);
ConnectedUsers.TryAdd(userid, existUserConnectionIds);
```

It has logic issue here. Every time the method is been excuted, it also add one ConnectionId into group.

Comment: I made the change that you suggested and I'm able to create a conversation and send a message but my other user doesn't receive it until he refresh the page. One extra data that maybe could be part of the issue is this?:  this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(`https://localhost:5001/sampleHub?userId=${user.id}`, { withCredentials: false})
      .build();

user.id can changes based on the logged user. Ex. For me is "/sampleHub?userId=1" and for my other user is "/sampleHub?userId=2"

Comment: @User1899289003 I haven't seen the ConversationCreated event was listened in your front-end project, this is the keypoint.

Comment: @User1899289003 I only find MessageReceived event was listened by using `this.hubConnection.on('MessageReceived'`. I will update my answer ^-^

Comment: I haven't implemented ConversationCreated yet basically because I'm not pretty sure what needs to be there. So, I'll really appreciate if you can give me a little bit of context of what should I do there.

Comment: @User1899289003 You don't need to do anything now, you just create a simple code and debug it, you will see the method I suggested was triggered. Then the issue was fixed, right ?

Comment: Unfortunately no :( but I think I know why... (_connectedUsers.TryGetValue(userId.ToString(), out string connectionId)) basically this is trying to compare the userId value with the _connectedUsers key instead of value. That's why I was using .Contains instead of TryGetValue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255242/discussion-between-jason-pan-and-user1899289003).